# Sorting an array of users and their XP's

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, algorithm, sorting

Let's say that i have an array of users like

`const array = [{userid: 1, xp: 36}, {userid: 2, xp: 61}, { userid: 3, xp: 13}......]`

How can i sort this that the user with the most XP is at the start of the array and the second goes to the second place in the array and so on. Thank you for your answers.
I know about sort(a,b), but that only seems to work on strings and numbers.

Comment: [Read the documentation for the sort function.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Comment: XP is a number so sort on b.xp-a.xp for descending

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a callback to `sort` that subtracts the `xp` values.

```js
const array = [{ userid: 1, xp: 36 }, { userid: 2, xp: 61 }, { userid: 3, xp: 13 }];
const res = array.toSorted((a, b) => b.xp - a.xp);
console.log(res);
```

---

**Note:** If you are using a version of Node.js prior to 20.x, you will either need to use `Array.prototype.sort` or a polyfill for `Array.prototype.toSorted`.

```js
// Quick-and-dirty polyfill
Array.prototype.toSorted = Array.prototype.toSorted ?? function(compareFn) {
  return [...this].sort(compareFn);
};
```

Comment: it works on snippet but i get an error that says .toSorted() is undefined. in Node 20.4.0, why?

Comment: ok i changed .toSorted() to sort() and it works, thank you very much

Comment: there is no array property called sorted as of my knowledge by marking it correct. I'm afraid you have done a mistake. My answer is based on Array sort which is the correct case.. Consider changing your decision for future referencing people. :)

Comment: @SelakaN Consider deleting your comment https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toSorted

Comment: @kagent263 `toSorted` is a newer method for creating a new sorted array without changing the original. Node may not support it yet. If you do not need immutability, then `array.sort` can be used instead to directly sort `array` in place.

Comment: @SelakaN "there is no array property called sorted" - Neither did my answer use any such property. It uses `toSorted`, the reference for which you can find on MDN.

Comment: @kagent263 I added a note to the bottom of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code for your problem:

```
     const array = [
  { userid: 1, xp: 36 },
  { userid: 2, xp: 61 },
  { userid: 3, xp: 13 },
  
];

// Custom comparison function
function compareByXP(user1, user2) {
  if (user1.xp < user2.xp) {
    return 1; // user2 should come before user1
  } else if (user1.xp > user2.xp) {
    return -1; // user1 should come before user2
  } else {
    return 0; // user1 and user2 are tied, maintain their original order
  }
}

// Sort the array based on XP
array.sort(compareByXP);

console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 1):

**You can provide object attribute xp to compare with another object xp via Javascript array `Sort()` method
Use the below for reference:**

```js
const array= [{userid: 1, xp: 36}, {userid: 2, xp: 61}, { userid: 3, xp: 13}];
console.log(array.sort((a, b) => b.xp - a.xp));
```

Comment: How is this different from what Unmitigated posted?

Comment: He has define it using some other method.. `toSorted()` I have achieved it via `Sort() ` method

Comment: it works on snippet but i get an error that says .toSorted() is undefined. in Node 20.4.0, why?

Comment: Its not `toSorted()` I have used here its `Sort()` it should work

Comment: @kagent263 can you check the updated  answer now ? It should work fine.. Dont forget mark it as correct and give upvote for the support. Thanks in advance

Comment: it works but accepted answer is the guy to answer first, his works too. sorry

Comment: But he has his answer with toSorted still.. Which in javascript theres no such method

Comment: Maybe you should update your JavaScript reference https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toSorted

Comment: The `toSorted` method is a newer immutability function that was added in Chrome 110 (February of this year).